# C#: TextChanged event of a Control not firing on "assign"

Tags: c#

Ok, here's the deal.

I have a graph, that "listens" to some labels' textfields, and graphs their values. It does this by adding the values on the TextChanged event.

The problem:
TextChanged only fires when the text has actually changed (obviously), and not when it has been assigned a new value.

What I need:
A way to detect if the Text field of label has been updated (assigned to), and all I have to work with is a reference to the Control (ie the Label).

I realize TextChanged wasn't designed for this, which is why I'm wondering if any of you guys have encountered a similar problem, and found a solution to it.

Answer (score 2):

The reason that your `TextChanged` event handler is not invoked in initial assignment of the text is that it is attached after the first text has been assigned (the designer seems to do things in this order by default). I would do like this:

- `TextChanged` calls another method (`UpdateGraph`)
- `UpdateGraph` collects necessary data and updates the graph
- Call `UpdateGraph` as the last thing done when loading the form

That will make sure that the graph is updated with the initial values. It is important that this call happens *after* the call to `InitializeComponent`.

Answer (score 1):

It is fairly common practice in "setters" to ignore trivial changes, for example:

```
public int Foo {
    get {return foo;}
    set {
        if(foo != value) {
            foo = value;
            OnFooChanged();
        }
    }
}
```

If `Text` is behaving like this, and you are relying on *all* updates causing an event, then it may not work as you want. I would probably try to find another way to do what you want; perhaps using an intermediate object that passes the values through.

Answer (score 0):

You could create your own control that inherits from that control and create your own Text property that will fire an event when assigned a new value.

Comment: If you mean `override`, then fine; but if "create your own" means `new Text {...}`, then that would be bad...

Comment: It's too early in the morning for me ;), but yeah - override